# Merging different android projects into single project which makes android app

Tags: android

i am working on android studio for my application. Usually the app has many features like maps, translator, splash-screen, weather etc almost 7 to 8 features. When i started working on the application for each feature, i have created different android project and now, once i am done building all features. I want to merge all the different projects (i.e each feature with respective project folder) into one android project so, it looks like an application with all features in it. (single android project). Can someone help me out ? please.

Comment: What should i do if i want to add buttons and the buttons are linked with respective feature. So when i click the button it should open related project and each project should have a respective button. All the buttons are placed on the home screen. I really need help and can someone help me out ? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Convert your separate projects into libraries and include them in one main app project
2. Copy all code any resources into a single project

Comment: what if i want to add buttons on the home screen, so that every feature in the application has respective button and once it is clicked it will run respective project files or activities. can you help me ? please.

Comment: You can do it with "com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" intent. You can create as many shortcuts as you want.

Comment: i am sorry when i mentioned home screen it is not the phone home screen. The home screen i mentioned is inside the application home screen which appears after the splash-screen. What do u mean by shortcut ? i think shortcut as in it creates on home screen of the phone not on the home screen of the application. Thank you !

Comment: I wanted to create shortcut for my features inside the application not shortcut for my application. So sorry for bothering you

Comment: what ever i am talking about is inside the application. It is to add buttons on homescreen of application where it has background image and has buttons. Buttons which has names like maps so when the user clicks on maps button on home screen of the application it should open maps. Same thing goes with other features not home screen of the home. Hope u understand what i mean

Comment: I don't see the problem then. Just create buttons for each feature. What exactly is the challenge?

Comment: The challenge is, like you said i will either copy paste everything into one project or convert into libraries but after doing that i want to create a button for each feature on the home-screen inside the application. My question is how will i achieve that one ? how should i create buttons after doing the process u told me ?

Comment: You need to have a main project. There you create a screen with the buttons.

Comment: so sorry for late reply, that is what i am asking. how to do that ? create a screen with buttons.

Comment: It is not just one button there should be atleast 5 0r 6 buttons.

Comment: If you know the number of buttons, you can just add them. Like regular button views. If it's dynamic, you should probably use a list with buttons or something like that.